# Python For loop not iterating over list (sys.argv)

Tags: python, ping, sys

I am trying to create a function that pings servers 4 times by taking hostnames in the command line arguments for running the script.

My problem is that is will ping google.com but nothing else in the list created using sys.argv.
I am just using pingable hostnames to test the script.

$ python3 pingy.py google.com youtube.com dummy.com

```
server_list = sys.argv[1:]

def ping(hosts):
  """
  Ping the host. If it is not pingable then break the script.
  """
  cmd = 'ping'
  # Ping machine 4 times.
  counter = 0
  for host in hosts:
    temp = subprocess.Popen([cmd, '-c 4', host], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
    output = str(temp.communicate())
    output = output.split("\n")
    output = output[0].split('\\')
    for count in output:
      if 'icmp_seq' in count:
        counter = counter + 1
    if  int((counter / 4) * 100) < 75:
      return '{} is less than 75% pingable'.format(host)
    return '{} is ping-able. Attempting to SSH into the machine.'.format(host)

print(ping(server_list))

example output:
dummy@dummy$ python3 cpu_eval.py google.com youtube.com cnn.com
 google.com is ping-able. Attempting to SSH into the machine.
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debuggin your code.

Comment: You return from the function at the end of the first loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns after the first iteration with value `google.com is ping-able. Attempting to SSH into the machine.`

Maybe try storing the output for each host in a list and then return the list after all iterations.

Comment: You were right. This was the primary problem. I ran into a few other problems after this point but the gist is that instead of appending the hosts to a list I used a dictionary. The values were {'host': ping counter}. Thank you for the assist.